# Webpack output file permissions

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm still pretty new to webpack and node, and I can't figure out what is setting the file permissions when I compile my JS modules. Currently it outputs the file with `-rw-------`, I'd like them to be `-rw-r--r--`. How do I set the file permissions for file output?

Comment: Bit late, but I ran into a similar problem and got 2 solutions that worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814142/output-an-executable-file-with-webpack