# Output an executable file with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm currently writing a node CLI tool and using webpack to bundle all of my assets. The entry point for this application is the js file where I actually parse `process.argv` and run a command (For reference, I'm using [tj/commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js)). This way, once the bundling is complete, I can enter `./<outputFile>` and it will run my application. The entry file looks like this:

```
import cli from './cli';

cli.parse(process.argv);

// If nothing was supplied
if (!process.argv.slice(2).length) {
  cli.outputHelp();
}
```

The bundling works fine but I can't get webpack to output the file as an executable. Once I run `chmod +x <outputFile>`, everything works perfectly. Is there a way that I can tell webpack what permissions to grant an output file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way is to use npm. Do you have an `package.json` in your project?
Add `"build": "webpack && chmod +x outputFile"` to the `scripts` section of your `package.json` and build your project by running `npm run build`.

Another way is to add one of these solutions to your `webpack.config.js`:

- simple plugin from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312715/run-command-after-webpack-build) which has `pre` and `post` build handlers
- use [on-build-webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/on-build-webpack), which executes js code at the end of the webpack build process

Whatever you choose, you'll need to add this piece of code:

```
var chmod = require('chmod');
chmod("outputFile", 500);
```

Comment: I do and had not considered that as an option. I'd like to, if possible, keep it all within webpack. If no one else posts a webpack-specific solution in the next day or 2, I'll accept this answer as it will definitely solve my problem.

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised no one said a thing about webpack's `BannerPlugin`. I do something similar than [@oklas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41814211/407456), but using `BannerPlugin` to add the specific node shebang:

```
{
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: '#!/usr/bin/env node',
      raw: true,
    }),
  ],
}
```

Then I simply add the execution permissions just adding `chmod` to my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack && chmod +x dist/mycommand"
}
```

Anyway, if you'd like to just use webpack you can use the `WebpackShellPlugin`, as said by oklas (note that using this forces you to add a new dependency, that's why I avoid using this approach):

```
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin')
{
  // [...]
  plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
      onBuildEnd:['chmod +x dist/mycommand'],
    }),
  ],
}
```

If you want to avoid including `WebpackShellPlugin` as a dependency, you can try to define a custom plugin based on `fs`, as said by [@taylorc93](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41842311/407456)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to append `#!/usr/bin/env node` on top of the file.
I ended up with this webpack plugin using `shelljs`

```
plugins: [
  // ...plugins,
  function () {
      this.plugin('done', () => {
      shell
        .echo('#!/usr/bin/env node\n')
        .cat(`${__dirname}/build/outputfile.js`)
        .to(`${__dirname}/commandname`)
      shell.chmod(755, `${__dirname}/commandname`)
    })
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Although @oklas's solution worked perfectly for me, I really wanted to try and keep all of this within webpack. I realized after a little more thought that this could all be done by a very simple plugin:

```
plugins: [
  // ...plugins,

  function() {
    this.plugin('done', () => {
      fs.chmodSync('bin/program-name.js', '755');

      // When the webpack output doesn't have a .js extension, minification fails :(
      fs.renameSync('bin/program-name.js', 'bin/program-name');
    })
  },
]
```

Use whichever way suits your needs!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it with Webpack 5:

```js
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
        banner: '#!/usr/bin/env node',
        raw: true,
        entryOnly: true
    }),
    function() {
        this.hooks.done.tapPromise('Make executable', async () => {
            await fs.chmod(`${__dirname}/dist/app.js`, '755');
        });
    }
]
```